# TextView ontouch

Tags: android

I have two lines in a TextView... When I touch the first line an action to be performed and when I touch the second line a different action needs to be performed.

Could you please help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to set a custom [ontouchlistener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setOnTouchListener%28android.view.View.OnTouchListener%29) to  your TextView and depending upon co-ordinates recieved you need to initiate differnt action